# modify script for duplicate renamed files

Tags: powershell

Using the code below in PowerShell, I'm renaming many pictures. How do I modify the code to manage duplicates? Note; many of the photos have the SAME CreationTime value. As they occur, I need them to be output as:

- yyyyMMdd-HHmm-1
- yyyyMMdd-HHmm-2
- yyyyMMdd-HHmm-3
- etc.

Script:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.CreationTime.toString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm") + ".jpg"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more to your scriptblock to check paths and cycle through until it finds something unique:

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $NewName=$_.CreationTime.toString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm") + ".jpg";
    $i=1
    While(Test-Path ".\$NewName"){
        $NewName=$_.CreationTime.toString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm") + "-$i.jpg"
        $i++
    }
    $NewName
}
```

**Edit:** Hm, I'm not sure why it would do that unless you didn't copy my code right. I ran it against a test folder and ended up with:

```
PS C:\temp\test> gci


Directory: C:\temp\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                         
-a----       10/12/2016  11:13 AM       35228885 20161012-1113.jpg                                                                                            
-a----       10/12/2016  11:28 AM       31413221 20161012-1128.jpg                                                                                            
-a----       10/12/2016  11:37 AM       33243498 20161012-1137.jpg                                                                                            
-a----       10/12/2016   4:42 PM        2110424 20161012-1642-1.jpg                                                                                          
-a----       10/12/2016   4:42 PM        3300892 20161012-1642-2.jpg                                                                                          
-a----       10/12/2016   4:42 PM        3295345 20161012-1642-3.jpg                                                                                          
-a----       10/12/2016   4:42 PM      101138881 20161012-1642.jpg
```

**Edit2:** Ok, fixed the issue where it can't manage more than 10 of a file with the same datetime.

Comment: Hi @TheMadTechnician - this resulted in many file names like 20161010-1114-01-02-03-04-05.jpg

Comment: It looks like when it has more than instances of a file with the same creationtime value, it creates the error. Here is an image of the file names it's creating. [link](http://imgur.com/a/TvAqX)

Comment: Gotcha... Ok, that's the RegEx replace. One sec, I can fix that.

Comment: Still getting a host of errors, mainly "PathTooLongException" - here is an image: [image](http://imgur.com/a/U1oZ8)

Comment: If you're getting PathTooLong errors then obviously you need to shorten the path. That's a windows limitation. I have no idea how you are ending up with that result, it doesn't make sense. I updated the answer so that you can't end up there now though.

Answer (score 0):

try this, but modify the path C:\temp with your path directory

```
  $listcouple=gci -File -Path "C:\temp" | select name, fullname, @{Name="Datstring";Expression={$_.CreationTime.toString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm") }} | group Datstring 

  foreach ($item in $listcouple)
  {
     if ($item.Count -gt 1)
     {
         $compteur=0 
         foreach ($value in $item.Group)
         {
            $compteur++
            $newname= $value.Datstring + "-" + $compteur.ToString() + ".jpg"
            Rename-Item -path  $value.fullname -newname    $newname 
         }
     }
     else
     {
        $newname= $item.Group[0].Datstring + ".jpg"
        Rename-Item -path  $item.Group[0].fullname -newname    $newname  
     }
  }
```